# How to stop applying both required scss and ng-invalid class scss in angular md2 input textarea control

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

I'm bit new to `css/scss`. I'm having the material `textarea` control where i am passing a regex, Also in the template of that component it has to be required control. in my `scss` and `template` file i have written the below code :

**textarea control:**

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="item" [name]="itemID" [pattern]="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required></textarea>
```

**textarea scss:**

```
 textarea {
    &.ng-invalid {
     border-bottom:1px solid #f00;
      ~ label {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
   }
  }
```

When the `textarea` is empty (If user deletes all the contents of it.) it highlights `textarea` control as follows:

[image]

In the above scenario i think it adds the required class as well as the css class i added. How do i apply one scss class in both the scenarios of regEx invalid and required not full filled without duplicating two bottom border lines as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use :

```
[pattern]="[a-zA-Z0-9]*" // Will compare 0 or more , so won't trigger with required
```

in place of

```
[pattern]="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"
```

---

Regex Operators :

```
a*  0 or more
a+  1 or more
a?  0 or 1
```

---

**From SCSS** :

```
textarea {
    &:not(.required).ng-invalid {
     border-bottom:1px solid #f00;
      ~ label {
        font-size: 14px;
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I'm seeking of a solution with scss. because its data driven web frontend where regEx gets changed dyanamically.

Comment: @SelakaN , I think in that case you can use `:not(.class_name)`

Comment: If you can come up with code based answer i would highly appreciate.. :)

Comment: @SelakaN , please check updated answer , I think that can help you

Comment: Can you explain what this scss class does? Will mark it as correct answer.  @Vivek Doshi

Comment: it will select textarea with no class named required but with class ng-invalid and apply the style